# Does it make sense to use feature importances based in gini index for other classifiers?

Tags: classification, feature-importances

I would like to know if makes sense running `yellowbrick.features.FeatureImportances` with a `RandomForestClassifier` model in order to find most influent features, and then fit a different model (e.g. `MLPClassifier`) with them.

Unfortunately, `FeatureImportances` doesn't support `MLPClassifier` to find features. Docs can be checked [here](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/model_selection/importances.html)

Answer (score 0):

Feature Importance Or Correlation is dependent on the approach used.

 It's like the model is saying, "*When I used my approach I find the particular feature very important.*"

When another model uses the same approach or an approach that is a superset of that approach, then it will be able to find that Importance too.

Few examples -

- *If RF finds a Feature very important and able to achieve a good score. It means the feature is a good predictor for the scenario but LinearRegression might not able to exploit the predictor*
- *Neural Network can exploit that since it can learn any function*
- *DecisionTree may struggle to recognize a good feature but easily seen by LinearRegression*. *See image below*
  [image]